# Socket Server refuses multiple connections with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server

I'm trying to do a multi-threaded python socket server, I created one thread that listens for connections and accepts them, within it I also creates sub-threads for each new connection.

PROBLEM: after a connection is established with one client , when another client tries to connect i get the following error in the client-side:

connectionrefusederror: [winerror 10061] no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it >>> in multiclientgui

I didn't wanna try multiprocessing to create a process for listening only,
Is it something in my code? Or in the OS (windows 10)? or what would it be?

```py
def serv():
    """ the main thread for listening"""

    global future ,soc ,add

    while True:

        s.listen(5)
        soc,add =s.accept()
        future =pool.submit(clientHandle,soc,add) #handling thread 
        print(" a new thread created to serve the client")

def clientHandle(socObj, address):
    print("thread been called")

    global client_data
    client_data =pd.DataFrame(columns=['Location','lat','long','speed','ID','Time'])

    client_sockets.append(socObj)
    client_addr.append(address)
    while True :
        content=socObj.recv(1024)
        if len(content)>0:
            data=content.decode()
            str(data)
            print(data)
```

Comment: Why is everything global? When a second connection occurs you overwrite `future`, `soc`, and `add` causing who knows what havoc.

Comment: that's a nice hint , thank you . @JamesKPolk

Comment: Move the `listen` call ahead of the loop. You can only call it once.